# Send div input into variable? JQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, input

I have tried to make an editable div using `contenteditable` so a person can put something in there and press a button. That should send the input text to the variable, but I can't seem to get it working. Could someone explain what I am doing wrong please?

The HTML:

```
<div id="InPut" style="position: absolute; left: 33.44%; top: 47.22%; width: 33.1%; height: 5.6%; right: auto; bottom: auto; border: 1px solid #ccc; min-height: 3%; overflow: hidden;" contenteditable>you can write in here</div>
<div id="Button" onclick="ButtonClick();" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; left: 44.25%; top: 55.94%; width: 11.5%; height: 8.6%; right: auto; bottom: auto; -webkit-background-size: 100%; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/PnznUlg.png); background-size: 100% 100%; background-position: 0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
```

My Javascript code:

```
var Name = document.getElementById("InPut");

function ButtonClick() {
    var Name = document.getElementById("InPut");
    $("#InPut").hide();
    $("#Button").hide();


}
```

And here is the Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/682pG/119/

Comment: Working JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/682pG/121/

Answer (score 1):

You need the [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method in jQuery:

```
function ButtonClick() {
    $("#InPut").hide();
    $("#Button").hide();
    var theInput = $("#InPut").html();
    alert(theInput);    
}
```

[Update Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/682pG/120/)

Comment: My Thanks sorry for the easy question.

Comment: @Ravvvennna it is only easy when you know the answer :)

Comment: It seems the text of the div isnt changing to the input that has been typed any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get value using .text() or .html() methods:

```
ButtonClick = function() {
    var Name = $('#InPut').text();
    console.log('Input text: ' + Name);
    $("#InPut").hide();
    $("#Button").hide();  
}
```

Working JSFiddle example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/682pG/121/

Comment: The div text in the div doesnt seem to be changing and is still saying you can write in here in my php file if i type in the div for example Rav and it posts the text is still you can write in here and i see this with by looking in the source it doesnt change any ideas ?

Comment: fixed check 1st answer.